# Use Git LFS with TFS 2015 Update 2 OnPremise

Tags: git, tfs-2015, git-lfs

TFS 2015 Update 2 brings Git LFS support, but when I tried to use it with the Brian Keller VS2015ALM virtual machine (upgraded to Update 2), I got this exception :

```
git-lfs/1.2.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.6.1; git 386c5d8)
git version 2.8.1.windows.1

$ git-lfs.exe smudge -- Image1.jpg
Error downloading object: Image1.jpg (968bda1e0a17e295e265311f93bc4e631e171
d776d51c6d7a43b52185c82631a)

Your user name must be of the form DOMAIN\user. It is currently brian%!(EXTRA st
ring=string)
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.Stack(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/techn/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/errors.go:566 +0x87
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.logPanicToWriter(0x1a42c0, 0xc082020020, 0x1b
54a0, 0xc0823ae1a0)
        C:/Users/techn/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/commands.go:195
 +0xf87
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.logPanic(0x1b54a0, 0xc0823ae1a0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/techn/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/commands.go:159
 +0x419
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.handlePanic(0x1b54a0, 0xc0823ae1a0, 0x0, 0x0)

        C:/Users/techn/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/commands.go:134
 +0x55
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.LoggedError(0x1b54a0, 0xc0823ae1a0, 0xa25980,
 0x21, 0xc082029c88, 0x2, 0x2)
        C:/Users/techn/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/commands.go:84
+0x89
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.smudgeCommand(0xc52680, 0xc0820f81e0, 0x1, 0x
2)
        C:/Users/techn/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/command_smudge.
go:79 +0xdd2
github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/_nuts/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
(0xc52680, 0xc0820f8040, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/techn/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/_nuts/github.com/
spf13/cobra/command.go:477 +0x3fb
github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/_nuts/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
(0xc536c0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/techn/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/_nuts/github.com/
spf13/cobra/command.go:551 +0x593
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.Run()
        C:/Users/techn/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/commands.go:99
+0x2a
main.main()
        C:/Users/techn/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/git-lfs.go:34 +0x135

ENV:
LocalWorkingDir=C:\Users\Brian\Source\Repos\DemoGitLfs
LocalGitDir=C:\Users\Brian\Source\Repos\DemoGitLfs\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=C:\Users\Brian\Source\Repos\DemoGitLfs\.git
LocalMediaDir=C:\Users\Brian\Source\Repos\DemoGitLfs\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=C:\Users\Brian\Source\Repos\DemoGitLfs\.git\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=1
BatchTransfer=true
GIT_DIR=.git
GIT_LFS_PATH=C:\Program Files\Git LFS
GIT_PREFIX=
```

This appends when I tried to push with git.exe and works after a first push with VS2015U2. But now I got this error when I try to re-clone my repo (failed on checkout) with git.exe or VS2015U2. By the way, VS completly crash in this case. I tried the same operations with VSTS, and no error occured (with git.exe, GitExtensions or VS2015U2). So it seems to be a problem with how credentials are provided but how to fix it ?

Repo steps :

1. Create a repo on TFS web portal
2. Clone it with VS or git
3. Execute "git lfs install"
4. Execute "git lfs filter track "*.jpg""
5. Add an image to workspace
6. Commit
7. Execute "git push origin master" => failed with git.exe
8. Execute "git push origin master" => works with VS
9. Add a second image and commit
10. The push now works with git.exe
11. Delete local repository
12. Clone repo => failed on checkout with git.exe or VS

I tried with "clone -n" to avoid immediate checkout, then I execute "git lfs install" and "git checkout master", same exception occured :
Your user name must be of the form DOMAIN\user. It is currently brian%!(EXTRA st
    ring=string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LFS: Git credentials for..XXXX..not found. Your user name must be of the form DOMAIN\user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986608/lfs-git-credentials-for-xxxx-not-found-your-user-name-must-be-of-the-form-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases) helps me to get it work.

Just use GCMW and at the first credential prompt (credentials are stored in the Windows Credential Manager) :

- username: "vsalm\brian"
- password: "P2ssw0rd"

And it works.

- Without GCMW it does not work.
- It works with the GCMW provided by the Git 2.8 installation, the manual installation of 1.2.2 and 1.3 (by adding "[credential]     helper = manager" in gitconfig)

Note: Clone with VS2015U2 doesn't work, a fix is plan in U3. More info: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2657886/cant-use-git-lfs-with-tfs-2015-update-2-onpremise

Answer (score 0):

According to the error exception, your TFS server is using "NTLM" for authentication. With this authentication, you must enter username:{DOMAIN}{user} and password:{pass}. So update your git credentials to this format and then try again. Check this link for details: [NTLM Authentication With Git-Lfs](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/proposals/ntlm.md).

> If the LFS server returns a "Www-Authenticate: NTLM" header, we will
>   set lfs.{endpoint}.access to be ntlm and resubmit the http request.
>   Subsequent requests will go through the ntlm auth flow.
>
> We will store NTLM credentials in the credential helper. When the user
>   is prompted for their credentials they must use
>   username:{DOMAIN}{user} and password:{pass}
>
> The ntlm protocl will be handled by an ntlm.go class that hides the
>   implementation of InitHandshake, Authenticate, and Challenge. This
>   allows miminal changesto the existing client.go class.